# Let function return arbitrary instances of type

Tags: haskell

I want a function to be able to return all possible instances (not sure if that's the right word) of a type. Like this (`fun` not working):

```
data T a where
    TInt :: Int -> T Int
    TStr :: String -> T String

fun :: Int -> T (forall a. a)
fun a | a >= 5    = TStr "a lot"
      | otherwise = TInt a
```

My end goal is to have an alias type `SomeT` that stands for arbitrary `T`.

I want to use this to parse type declarations of a DSL. I have int and string types and want to have one parsing function that parses them all.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an existential type wrapper.

```
data T a where
    TInt :: Int -> T Int
    TStr :: String -> T String

data SomeT where
    S :: T a -> SomeT

fun :: Int -> SomeT
fun a | a >= 5    = S $ TStr "a lot"
      | otherwise = S $ TInt a

foo :: SomeT -> Maybe (T Int)
foo (S x@(TInt _)) = Just x
foo _              = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

The usual solution to this are simply [algebraic data types](https://wiki.haskell.org/Algebraic_data_type).

```
data T = TInt Int | TStr String

fun :: Int -> T
fun a | a >= 5   = TStr "a lot"
      | othrwise = TInt a
```

---

However, your exact problem can be solved, using typeclasses for ad-hoc polymorphic behavior:

```
class TT a where
    tt :: a -> T a

instance TT Int where
    tt = TInt

instance TT String where
    tt = TString

fun :: (TT a) => Int -> T a
fun a | a >= 5    = tt "a lot"
      | otherwise = tt a
```

Comment: I want to be able to restrict type `T` in other data types, though. I wouldn't be able to require all `Integral` types (for example) without a type variable.

Comment: @snøreven You cannot hide polymorphic types under a concrete one in Haskell. Either you will have type variables everywhere, or you have to stick to concrete types. In your example, `fun` returns different types depending on the argument, which is also not possible (without some new dependent-types extensions).